# Objective-C fast enumeration and asynchronous server operations. Model help?

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, for-loop

If I have a method called "-uploadToServer:(Object *)objectToUpload", and a mutable array of several Objects, and I want to upload each object one after the other, how could I best handle this?

There are three important considerations:

1. Don't want NSOperation because I don't want to deal with threading issues
2. Need to wait for notification of task completion before continuing
3. Server calls are asynchronous and non-blocking

Here is some code I already have:

```
for (Object *task in objectsToUpload) {
    [self uploadToServer:task];
    //need to wait to get notification that upload completed
}


-(void)uploadToServer:(Object *)objectToUpload {
    //perform asynchronous server operation here
    //either block callback or delegate to notify
    //self that upload finished
}
```

Seeing the above, how do you think I should handle this?

Comment: It would appear that two of your requirements are contradictory.  The idea of waiting for notification before completing and performing an asynchronous upload conflict.  You also state you don't want to use NSOperationQueue because of threading issues.  NSOperationQueue is specifically designed as a mechanism to abstract threading and avoid common pitfalls of manually threaded code.  What threading issues are you not wanting to deal with?

Comment: I don't know, threads are supposed to be scary and used with the utmost discretion, and I feel like I've already coded the majority of my server operations with asynchronous delegate callback patterns.  It's only now I realize that I want to put them in a loop.

Comment: NSOperationQueue and other technologies like GCD are intended to abstract out threading to avoid common issues with traditional threading.  NSOperationQueue seems like a good solution to your problem.  One of the answers to this question does a pretty good job of laying out a plan of attack, I recommend going with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Don't want NSOperation because I don't want to deal with threading issues

Honestly, I think this is your easiest option.  The only other way is to do asynchronous IO and use the run loop.

With NSOperation, you'd need two different kinds of operation called e.g. `UploadOperation` and `NotifyOperation`:  one to upload an object and one to send a notification to the main thread when everything is done.

Then you'd loop through thwe objects putting them all on an `NSOperationQueue` in an `UploadOperation`, each one dependent on the previous one (`addDependency:`).  Finally, you'd put the `NotifyOperation` on the queue dependent on the last `UploadOperation`.

The `NotifyOperation` overrides `main` as follows

```
-(void) main
{
    [someObjectEgViewController performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(finishedUpload)
                                                 withObject: nil 
                                              waitUntilDone: NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your response is making me reconsider my options.  I was just under the impression that making iOS apps thread safe was a big deal, and to stay away if possible.

Comment: Making iOS apps thread safe is no harder than any other platform, in fact things like NSOperation make it much easier.

Answer (score 3):

`objectsToUpload` is an `NSMutableArray` of tasks

```
-(void)uploadToServer{

//check if there is a task available
if (objectsToUpload.count > 0){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {

        //get first task
        id nextTask = [objectsToUpload objectAtIndex:0];

        //do something

        //complete async
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

            //remove completed task
            [objectsToUpload removeObject:nextTask];

            //complete async upload task, check or notify and or start the next task
            BOOL shouldDoNextTask = [self check];
            if (shouldDoNextTask){
                [self uploadToServer];
            }

        });

    });
}
```

}

Comment: I like this, although I've never used the dispatch queue.  I'm a fan of blocks as well.  Also solves the problem of removing items from the array during enumeration, since it's not a for loop!  +1

Comment: This is a nice alternative to `NSOperation`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you **do not** need to wait for the task to complete.  What you need is to respond to the task's completion.

[NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will provide a delegate with callback methods.

Comment: I'm already using a wrapper on NSURLConnection and all of the callbacks are integrated in it and abstracted